# Linux command for data filtering

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have one file which contains several lines of data

```
editPin -pin phy_inst/i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[0] ctrl_soft_phy_inst/hbm_ch_tile_4_hbm_tile_inst/o_phy_row_cmd_p1[0] -assign {1443.0305 184.62} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
editPin -pin phy_inst/i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[1] ctrl_soft_phy_inst/hbm_ch_tile_4_hbm_tile_inst/o_phy_row_cmd_p1[0] -assign {1444.0305 185.62} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
```

and i want to perform some operation and i want to set my line like this

```
eval editPin -pin i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[0]  -assign { 0 [ expr 1443.0305 184.62]} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
eval editPin -pin i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[1]  -assign { 0 [ expr 1444.0305 185.62]} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
```

I used these commands individually, I tried them, and it worked how I wanted the structure.

```
awk '{$4=""; print $0}' all_pin 
awk '{print "eval " $0}' all_pin 
sed -e /^editPin/'{ s#phy_inst/## ; s/{/{ 0 [ expr / ; s/}/]}/ ; }' all_pin
```

but when i used these commands together its not giving the result how i want

```
cat all_pin | awk '{$4=""; print $0}' all_pin | awk '{print "eval " $0}' all_pin | sed -e /^editPin/'{ s#phy_inst/## ; s/{/{ 0 [ expr / ; s/}/]}/ ; }' all_pin
```

may i know the solution for this

and i want to perform addition operation for this block

```
-assign { 0 [ expr 1443.0305 362.764+X]}
```

***X*** is a constant value and i want to add ***X*** to ***362.764***
using command.I tried but I got the wrong answer

```
awk '{print $10+100}' all_pin
```

please help me to get out of this

Comment: For your second part question, would you be happy with `-assign { 0 [ expr 1443.0305 184.62 ]}` instead of `-assign { 0 [ expr 1443.0305 184.62]}`? (There's an extra space between the second fractional number and the closing `[}`.)

Answer (score 0):

In your combined command you are still specifying a source file for each item in the pipeline:

> ```
> cat all_pin | awk '{$4=""; print $0}' all_pin | awk '{print "eval " $0}' all_pin | sed -e /^editPin/'{ s#phy_inst/## ; s/{/{ 0 [ expr / ; s/}/]}/ ; }' all_pin
> #   ^source                           ^again                             ^and again                                                                    ^and still again
> ```

Instead, you should let each command read from its predecessor. Here, I've combined the two `awk` commands and discarded the unnecessary `cat`:

```
awk '{ $4=""; print "eval " $0}' all_pin |
    sed -e '/^editPin/ { s#phy_inst/## ; s/{/{ 0 [ expr / ; s/}/]}/ ; }'
```

Depending on the answer to my [comment question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721603/linux-command-for-data-filtering/721613#comment1368145_721603) the second part may be equally straightforward, and I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: As you mentioned here I already tried this, before posting a question, and also now I have tried, if I mention the filename "all_pin" for awk it will work (your solution) and if I mention the file name on both commands it will work only for sed command.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this awk

```
 {  for(i=1; i<=NF ; i++ ) {
        if ( $i ~ /^phy_inst/ ) {
                $i=substr($i,10) ;
                $(i+1)="" ; }
        if ( $i == "-assign" ) {
                $(i+1)="{ 0 [ expr " $(i+1) ;
                $(i+2)=$(i+2) "+" X " ]}" ;
                }
 }
        $1 = "eval " $1 ;
         print ;
 }
```

to be called with (replace foo_bar with proper value)

```
awk -v X=foo_bar -f SE.awk all_pin
```

yielding

```
eval editPin -pin i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[0]  -assign { 0 [ expr {1443.0305 184.62}+foo_bar ]} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
eval editPin -pin i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[1]  -assign { 0 [ expr {1444.0305 185.62}+foo_bar ]} -layer M10 -pinWidth 0.038 -pinDepth 0.395 -fixOverlap false -fixedPin -snap MGRID
```

where awk basically parse line by line,

- parsing is done by looping on all "field", `awk` use `NF` variable (Number of Field, see `man awk`)
- add eval in first field
- strip `phy_inst/` string, delete following field (implicit specification)
- edit values after `-assign` field
- insert value of `X` variable (this must be called on command line)(and a poor choice for a variable name)

---

Untested

```
    if ( $i == "-assign" ) {
            $(i+1)="{ 0 [ expr " ($(i+1)+X) ;
            $(i+2)=($(i+2) + X) " ]}" ;
            }
```

Just add X value to proper field.

Comment: That's great but i want to perform some arithmetic operation inside this "{ 0 [ expr {1443.0305    184.62}+foo_bar ]} "  ,,,,  its like " { 0 [ expr { 1443.0305 
  184.62+foo_bar } ]} "  if foo_bar =1000  then the result will be " { 0 [ expr { 1443.0305    1846.2} ]} "

Comment: Thanks, for the update. i got it i was working on that

Comment: what is NF? in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Why not use tcl for the addition?  Here is an example that just changes the expression to a have a nested expr so you can adjust the second value in tcl.

```bash
$ echo editPin -pin phy_inst/blah args  -assign {1443.0305 184.62} -options | \
    sed  '/editPin.*phy_inst/s/assign {\([0-9.]*\) \([0-9.]*\)}/assign { 0 [ expr \1 [ expr \2 + 123.3]]}/'
# returns editPin -pin phy_inst/blah args -assign { 0 [ expr 1443.0305 [ expr 184.62 + 123.3]]} -options
```

That way the sed is just a simple string replacement, and you aren't attempting to do any floating point math in shell/awk/bc/etc.